# Intermitent SecurityError DOM Exception 18 on facebook connect

Tags: facebook, safari, facebook-javascript-sdk, mobile-safari, hello.js

The error is `SecurityError: DOM Exception 18` and it happens at replaceState@https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbds.js line 9, pos 2343

We do facebook login using [hello.js](https://github.com/MrSwitch/hello.js/)

It seems that it is having issues accessing `replaceState`, and:

- only happens in safari, desktop and mobile (9.0 and 9.1)
- happens a few days, then stops for weeks, then comes back

I haven't been able to reproduce it, we have clientside error reporting where I see these errors bursts come and go.

Question is, has anyone experienced and solved this?

Answer (score 1):

We've been experiencing this over the last few days with replaceState in JQuery mobile.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/36650

**Summary**

A simple replication case, which gives dom exception 18 in the Safari console:

```
for (var i=0 ; i<=100; i++) { window.history.replaceState(null, null, "http:/www.apple.com/"); }
```

Response from Apple:

> This issue behaves as intended based on the following: This is by
>   design. We fixed a security bug in iOS that abused
>   pushState/replaceState.

**Resolution**

For us the solution was simply to remove the offending line from the JQuery mobile framework:

```
window.history.replaceState( state, state.title || document.title, href );
```

I appreciate that this is probably not helpful to your case but at least it might help explain the behaviour you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

No known solution (other than update) yet.

WebKit bug tracker:

- https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=137760
- https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=140443

PouchDB GH Issue:

- https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/3382

Comment: those bugs doesn't look related to `replaceState`, instead they mention browser db issues, but, I could be failing to see the connection

Comment: Agreed. I'm intermittently getting a `SecurityError: DOM Exception 18` from jQuery... more digging is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Safari is set to block cookies (and other storage).

Settings > Safari > Block Cookies > 'Always Allow'

See also: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/125584/broken-safari-dom-exception-18